# How to fix these vulnerabilities by manual review?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, security

I did `npm audit` and `npm audit fix`.

But some vulnerabilities needs manual review.

So, How to upgrade these packgaes by manually?
[These packages needs manual upgrade.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dx1W.png)

Answer (score 1):

The audit command will install semver-major updates when the `--force` flag is used.  This is not default behavior because it may introduce breaking changes in updated dependencies.

```sh
npm audit fix --force
```

Alternatively, you can manually update a specific dependency with an install command.

```sh
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@latest --save-dev
```

In this particular case, *uglifyjs-webpack-plugin* is deprecated and suggests *terser-webpack-plugin* as an alternative.  You may want to use that package instead.

```sh
npm uninstall uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
npm install terser-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```